# Is it possible to start a program with a missing shared library

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I'm running Linux and have a situation like this:
A binary file 'bin1' loads via dlopen 'shared1.so' which is linked with 'shared2.so' and 'shared3.so'.

if 'shared2.so' or 'shared3.so' is missing the program 'bin1' won't run.
There are runs that I know that I won't touch any code from 'shared2.so' and I want 'bin1' to be able to run even when this library is missing, can this be done ?

Comment: You could load library on demand using dlopen and dlsym. However, that requires you to modify the shared1.so

Comment: Try to `touch shared3.so shared2.so`.  This way the files exist, but empty.  This might help

Answer (score 0):

You could ship program with dummy `shared2.so` library. You might need to add dummy functions which `shared1` expects to find there. This can be done manually or via automatic tool like [Implib.so](https://github.com/yugr/Implib.so).